# How to use the geoip database in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, geoip

I would like to access the geolite database of maxmind from my java/scala code.
http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite

I have in my mind a solution that is scalable like elasticsearch and that has no single point of failure, no bottle neck, low latency and low maintenance cost (no need to install a local database on each web server).

So I wondered if there is already a solution for importing and using the geolite data with elasticsearch?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html)

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I see that logstash includes the geoip database and can look up automatically geoip and create geoPoints in elasticsearch. Unfortunately, I cannot find any details how I could use it for my case, because I wish to look up geoips from my code directly. The only usage I see is to put the id into logstash and search in Elasticsearch for the result and then delete the Elasticsearch entry, that looks like a bad architecture. Btw.: Is logstash a single-server or a cluster solution?

Comment: The guide for using geoip for ES can be found here => http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html

Comment: Thanks deagh, I cannot find in the documentation how to query any IP address from java code?